# convert right side of join of one to many tables into an array in knex

Tags: express, join, knex.js

Please help 
I have table ideas that look like this

```js
ideas = {
  id,
  title,
  abstract,
  background,
  classification,
  technicalfeild,
  tag,
  user_id,
}
```

and a table idea-images that look like this

```js
idea-images = {
  id,
  idea_id,
  banner,
  image_details
}
```

they have a one to many relations. I need to select all the ideas that have public tags and find the images in the idea-image table and attached the images as an array to the idea since the idea can have many images.
here is my code

```js
return knex('ideas')
  .where('tag', 'published')
  .rightJoin('idea-images', 'ideas.id', '=', 'idea-images.idea_id')
  .orderBy('ideas.created_at', 'desc');
```

and here what it will return

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'blahhh ',
    abstract: ' blahh',
    background: 'blahhh',
    classification: 'consumer product',
    technicalfeild: '',
    description: 'blah....... ',
    summary: '',
    claims: 'blahhhh',
    tag: 'published',
    user_id: 3,
    created_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    updated_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    idea_id: 2,
    banner: 'Drawing-2',
    image_details: 'blahhh',

  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'blahhh ',
    abstract: ' test',
    background: 'test',
    classification: 'blahhhh',
    technicalfeild: '',
    description: 'test ',
    summary: '',
    claims: 'test',
    tag: 'published',
    user_id: 2,
    created_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    updated_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    idea_id: 3,
    banner: 'test',
    image_details: 'test',

  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'My new car ',
    abstract: ' test',
    background: 'test',
    classification: 'consumer product',
    technicalfeild: '',
    description: 'test ',
    summary: '',
    claims: 'test',
    tag: 'published',
    user_id: 2,
    created_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    updated_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    idea_id: 3,
    banner: 'test2',
    image_details: 'test2',

  }
]
```

for some reason it creates a new idea if the idea has 2 images!!! I really have no idea how to make the image data into an array.

Comment: I want the result to be like this 
```
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'My new car ',
    abstract: ' test',
    background: 'test',
    classification: 'consumer product',
    technicalfeild: '',
    description: 'test ',
    summary: '',
    claims: 'test',
    tag: 'published',
    user_id: 2,
    created_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
    updated_at: 2020-02-21T00:10:43.692Z,
   images: [
{
             id:1
             idea_id: 3,
             banner: 'test2',
             image_details: 'test2',
}
]
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions,

1. Using group_concat, suitable when each idea has small amount of images, the query looks like 
   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74qcRt3siGF2sxT4ykqh9t/1
2. Split into 2 queries, fetch ideas and then fetch all images by relevant ideas

```
const ideas = await knex('ideas')
  .where('tag', 'published')
  .orderBy('ideas.created_at', 'desc');
const ideaImages = await knex('ideaImages').whereIn('ideaId', ideas.map(idea => idea.id));

mergeData(ideas, ideaImages);
```

Comment: Hey @Felixmosh, thanks for your comment. I did try left join and still getting the same result. I have a one to many relations between these two tables and want to get the images as an array attached to my idea table. but the left join is giving me the same result as right join and join

Comment: thanks a lot for updating your solution, I ended up using solution 2 and merge the two data arrays.